# How to get the output of Calories

Tags: while-loop

When running this program we are able to get the BMR output but it won't plug into the equation to give us calorie output. It seems to me like it's completely ignoring the activity part of the code. We had a user input 1 2 or 3 in a different part of the code. Any help will be appreciated.

```
public class Calculate
{
   static UserInput dataInput = new UserInput();
   static double BMR;
   static double calorie;
   public void calculateReturn()
   {
      output();
      
   }
   
   private void output()
   {
      System.out.println("Your daily caloric needs are: " + calorie);
      calculate();  
   }
   
   private void calculate()
   {
   UserInput dataInput = new UserInput();
   if (dataInput.getGender() == 1)
   {
      maleBMR();
   }
   else
   {
      femaleBMR();
   }
   activity();
   }
   private void maleBMR()
   {
      double BMR = (66 + (6.23 * dataInput.getWeight()) + (12.7 * dataInput.getHeight()) - (6.8 * dataInput.getAge()));
      System.out.println("BMR: " + BMR);
   }      
    
   private void femaleBMR()
   {
         double BMR = (665 + (4.35 * dataInput.getWeight()) + (4.7 * dataInput.getHeight()) - (4.7 * dataInput.getAge()));
         System.out.println("BMR: " + BMR);
   }
   private void activity()
   {
   double calorie;
   if (dataInput.getActivity() == 1)
   {
      calorie = (BMR * 1.2);
   }
   else if (dataInput.getActivity() == 2)
   {
      calorie = (BMR * 1.5);
   }
   else 
   {
      calorie = (BMR * 1.9);
   }

   }
}
```

Comment: I also just realized It's not returning the correct number for BMR either

Answer (score 0):

You are defining two calorie variables: one of them is a global variable defined within the Calculate class and the other is defined inside the activity() function. That second calorie variable is only visible in your activity function. So activity function will only change the value of your local calorie variable not the global one.

Comment: Should I get rid of the variable defined in the activity() function then?

Comment: You can do it many ways, you can get rid of the local variable or you change the signature of your activity function from void to double. Then you can return the calculated calories instead of just calculating them inside the function.

Comment: After I change the signature to void it gives me an error saying I have a missing return statement.

Comment: It'd be better for you to look at some fundamentals about object-oriented programming, access scopes, functions, SOLID principles etc. You should be knowing what you are doing before doing it ;)